# Obtener un conjunto de registros con los datos actualizados de una tabla

Tags: mysql

Es posible acceder a un registro de datos que contengan los campos que han sido actualizados en una tabla?
Cuando se realiza un Update en MySql los valores anteriores se remplazan completamente o de alguna manera son almacenados?

Comment: Pues, si no te lo haces tú mismo, no. Puedes hacer un disparador que, antes de realizar el `UPDATE`, haga un `INSERT` a una tabla de valores históricos... Inténtalo y, si no te sale, comparte tu código y te ayudamos

Comment: Respuesta rápida, **NO**. Una buena opción es lo que ya te comentaron antes. Los pasos serían `SELECT > INSERT > DELETE`